Azure Logic App returns metadata instead of SQL query results when invoked via HTTP trigger
I'm working with an Azure Logic App that is supposed to execute a SQL query and return the results when triggered via an HTTP GET request. However, instead of receiving the SQL query results, I'm getting metadata or properties of the response.
When I check the run history in the Azure Portal, I see the correct SQL query results, which look like this:
{
  "ResultSets": {
    "Table1": [
      {
        "PRODUCT_KEY": "2771497f-6b51-4607-af12-b81f946c9752",
        "INVENTORY_ITEM_ID": 300001679044591,
        "ITEM_NUMBER": "278",
        "ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "Ring, key; tamper-proof...",
        // ... additional fields ...
      }
    ]
  },
  "OutputParameters": {}
}


However, when I invoke the Logic App via the HTTP GET URL, I receive a response that contains metadata about the Logic App run instead of the SQL query incorrect results:
{
  "properties": {
    "status": "Running",
    "outputs": {},
    "response": {
      "status": "Waiting"
    },
    // ... additional metadata ...
  },
  "id": "/workflows/...",
  "name": "08584732105684415113523970809CU31",
  "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs"
}



Code :
Checked the Response Action Configuration:
Ensured that the Response action is set to return the body of the SQL query action.
Removed any operationOptions to make sure the response is synchronous.
Adjusted the Response Action Expression:
Modified the expression in the Response action to specifically reference the SQL query results:
java
Copy code
@body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)').ResultSets.Table1
i have tried most of this :

Verified the HTTP Trigger Settings:
Confirmed that the Asynchronous Response option is disabled in the HTTP trigger settings.
Tested the Logic App with a Simple Response:
Changed the Response action to return a static message, which works correctly when invoked.
Checked the Run History:
No errors are reported; the Logic App run shows successful execution with the correct outputs in the run history.

We need to figure out how to use the query result so that api get
calls has the data

Code :
{
"definition": {
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
 "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "triggers": {
   "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
     "type": "Request",
     "kind": "Http",
     "inputs": {
       "method": "GET",
       "schema": {}
     }
   }
 },
 "actions": {
   "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": {
     "type": "ApiConnection",
     "inputs": {
       "host": {
         "connection": {
           "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql-1']['connectionId']"
         }
       },
       "method": "post",
       "body": {
         "query": "select * from dwh.dim_product where item_number=\n'278'"
       },
       "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('syn-dlr-eda-prd.sql.azuresynapse.net'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('Syndw'))}/query/sql"
     },
     "runAfter": {}
   },
   "Response": {
     "type": "Response",
     "kind": "Http",
     "inputs": {
       "statusCode": 200,
       "body": "@triggerOutputs()?['queries']"
     },
     "runAfter": {
       "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": [
         "Succeeded"
       ]
     },
     "operationOptions": "Asynchronous"
   },
   "Compose": {
     "type": "Compose",
     "inputs": "@body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1']",
     "runAfter": {
       "Response": [
         "Succeeded"
       ]
     }
   }
 },
 "outputs": {},
 "parameters": {
   "$connections": {
     "type": "Object",
     "defaultValue": {}
   }
 }
},
"parameters": {
 "$connections": {
   "value": {
     "sql-1": {
       "id": "/subscriptions/c6119c4d-7517-4020-96e2-e98vjfj5d52/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/southcentralus/managedApis/sql",
       "connectionId": "/subscriptions/c6119c0-96e2-e985d5c5xoxe2/resourceGroups/RG-DWH-DEV/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-1",
       "connectionName": "sql-1"
     }
   }
 }
}
} ```


On StackOverflow, we can't really help people when all they post is cropped screenshots of some visual-editor (I'm saying that your post is missing far too many details that are critical to troubleshooting your problem). Instead, please go to the Code View of your Logic App workflow and paste that into this SO question.

Thanks for pointing this out, i have attached the code

Looking at the code your Response body has this value: "body": "@triggerOutputs()?['queries']"

Methinks this is caused by "operationOptions": "Asynchronous" in your Response step: it measns that the Logic App's HTTP endpoint will immediately return an asynchronous-status response for all requests because the SQL query (I assume) does not run instantly (your use of SELECT * means you won't benefit from any INCLUDES columns in your indexes - you should not be using SELECT * in a production query anyway). You need to decide how long-running SQL queries should be handled, because Azure is not going to stall an incoming HTTP request for an hour if the SQL takes that long to run.

I got this from my existing project.
This is the action

I have a previously created API connection for my SQL Server database.
Action body

Run History


Output body (DB Record)

After getting the DB record, I sent an email based on the returned DB record.


For To section

For Subject Section


If you need any help with the API connection let me know

thats the thing when i looking into run history its all correct however when i used the actual api url i get paramter details of the api.
i think something is wrong with what i pass in response's body

i need to know how to send that query result when my get api is called

I updated the answer, can you confirm that

Should i enable asyc mode otherwise i get
ActionResponseSkipped
The execution of template action 'Response' is skipped: the client application is not waiting for a response from service.

thank you , but the issue was run history shows response is skipped but looking into api data it reflects correctly when not in async mode
